# Declare variable "let" in javascript ECMAScript6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is it possible to declare variable named let when I can't declare const or var. I know I will never do that , but I am just curious if there is reasonable explanation. So I can do:

```
var let = 5;
let x = 3;
x + let -> 8
```

Why is this even possible?

Comment: I don't think this is a wise code to write. I don't think that should be authorized. Working with babel and webpack: that doesn't work for me. Could you share your dev env?

Comment: @Damien Any browser console and node.js env

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Developer Network site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords) under `Future reserved keywords`:

> The following are only reserved when they are found in strict mode code:

which includes `let`.

However, `const` and `var` are listed under `Reserved keywords as of ECMAScript 6` and [this document](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords) shows the history where they were originally reserved in ECMAScript 1.

#### [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) before any other statements.

What is strict mode?

> ECMAScript 5's strict mode is a way to opt in to a restricted variant of JavaScript. Strict mode isn't just a subset: it intentionally has different semantics from normal code. Browsers not supporting strict mode will run strict mode code with different behavior from browsers that do

Answer (score 0):

i think you can still write this in browser's console because the lately support ES6 and let may still not blocked to be defined.